# IAM & Admin Roles issue GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase

The IAM & Admin Roles some issue with load the Roles. I am not able to manage roles and also my App Engine default service account is disable. and also my firebase not working which is linked to this project.

There is screenshots:
[Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/proxr.png)
[Service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKcYr.png)